# Render Unlit fog transparent for a logo

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency, lighting

I have a problem with rendering a logo which consists of two main parts :

- Front half of the logo is a rather normal solid set of objects creating my font.
- Back half of the logo is a slightly smaller version of the same logo emitting light.

I would now like to create a glow effect by lighting up fog with the emitting objects...

As such, I am able to create the desired effect in Cycles. There is only the problem that I need a thick set of fog in order to create the desired fog... I would now like to be able to render it in a way where I only get the colourfull slighty transparent fog rendered and everything else fom the fog transparent. As of now I am only able to create my desired image with black background because of the fog.

I would be very gratefull for help on this problem !

[image]

Comment: Did you enable Render Tab > Film > Transparent ON ?

Comment: Yes i am also abel to render out a Transparent background if I leave the fog out

Comment: Then just keep your transparent film and your glare and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

### Scene setup

Let's say you have this scene, with emission objects. First you want to enable *Film transparency*.

[image: Scene setup]

### Compositing

Then in the compositor, enable *Use Nodes* and add a *Glare* node as follows :

[image: Add glare to compositor]

By setting the *Mix* to 1, you'll only get the glare without the original image.

Glare/bloom effects are meaned to be used with an additive *Blend mode*. This means that you'll only add values to your pixels. Thus, black won't do anything and brighter parts will add brightness. My setup here could be better, by enabling the *Emit* render pass, and use it as input of the *Glare* node. In that case, there will no transparency at all.

So my point is, to my knowledge, a *Glare/bloom* layer should not be transparent. Or at least it doesn't have to be.

### Compositing example

The final setup would look like that :

[image: Compositing example]

You can then decrease the glare with the *Factor* value of the *Add* node. Or you could increase the effect of the glare.